# Import MultipartEntityBuilder jar into eclipse

Tags: android, apache, jar

I am currently making an app that needs to send images/videos with information about it (such as id's/length/date ...).

I usually use JSON but i'm having OOM issue with large images/videos. I googled quite a bit and saw everything I needed in *MultipartEntityBuilder*.

I downloaded the HttpClient and HttpCore at http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi in order to import them in my application but I can't find any .jar on the website.

There are tar.gz and .zip but I can't achieve to do anything with these files.

Any ideas on how can I get the .jar files or how can I import these tar.gz/.zip into my project ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary .zip folders contain a library folder, which contains the appropriate jar files.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend looking into a dependency manager such as Maven or, my favorite, Gradle. They take care of downloading the jars and have all the jars maintained online. It also makes it easier when you want to publish you app.